# Regex any number between two html tags

Tags: c#, regex, integer

Currently I am using this code:

```
    var regex = new Regex(@"<span id=""point_total"" class=""tooltip"" oldtitle="".*?"" aria-describedby=""ui-tooltip-0"">(.*?)</span>"); <br />
    var match = regex.Match(@"<span id=""point_total"" class=""tooltip"" oldtitle="".*?"" aria-describedby=""ui-tooltip-0"">"+ "{n}"+ "</span>"); <br />
    var result = match.Groups[1].Value; <br />
        return result; <br />
```

How can I alter the code so that where {n} is, it can be equal to any integer?
Sorry if I didn't word that too well

Comment: `\d+` Nontrivial trivial comment

Comment: Consider using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"{n}"` to `"\d+"` and you're all set.

```
var match = regex.Match(@"<span id=""point_total"" class=""tooltip"" oldtitle="".*?"" aria-describedby=""ui-tooltip-0"">\d+</span>");
```

**Edit:** I may have misunderstood your question, you want to change your regex from:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<span id=""point_total"" class=""tooltip"" oldtitle="".*?"" aria-describedby=""ui-tooltip-0"">(.*?)</span>");
```

to:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<span id=""point_total"" class=""tooltip"" oldtitle="".*?"" aria-describedby=""ui-tooltip-0"">\d+</span>");
```

Comment: It's a literal string, so just `\d+` is what you need.

Comment: when i use MessageBox.Show(findstring) to call the code above it returns the value "\d+" only

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the pattern to match digits?  `"\d"`